# Strange display issue with JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

In the following simple code I simply create a Frame, and add a `JPanel` and `menubar` to it.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;
    public MainFrame()
    {
        super("Coordinate Geometry Visualiser");
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        add(drawPanel);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');

        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        newItem.setMnemonic('N');
        fileMenu.add(newItem);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        editMenu.setMnemonic('E');
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
    }
}
```

Draw Panel code -

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public DrawPanel()
    {
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(100, 50, 150, 100);
    }
}
```

and finally the application with `main()`

```
public class CGVApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame appFrame = new MainFrame();
        appFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        appFrame.setSize(300, 275);
        appFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

On running the application inside **eclipse**, this is what i get -
[image]   [image]

Why the double **menubar** and **line**? This is very annoying. On cycling through applications or when a popup comes the redrawn window is fine (Right side image).

Also in my **DrawPanel** `paintComponent` i have set background as black, but no effect?

What is the reason for above two issues? Please help!

Comment: You normally set the background color when initializing the components, not in the paint methods. Try to move that line to the constructor. - As for the doubling problem: it's just a guess but try adding this line before opening the frame: `System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true");`

Comment: hey thanks, moving(or commenting) this line `setBackground(Color.BLACK);` from paint to constructor solved the problem of double line and menu. But the panel is still not black. Maybe you should add your comment as answer. BTW `setProperty` didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling Container.paintComponents() method. It must be `super.paintComponent(g)`.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g); //super.paintComponents(g);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(100, 50, 150, 100);
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem! And yes @JBNizet - Please undelete your post.

Comment: I undeleted it.It's more informative, but doesn't solve the issue as correctly as yours.

Comment: @AVD: Very true, if eclipse didn't make life so easy, i wouldn't do such a mistake!

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc mentions that

- isOpaque must be true
- that depending on the L&F, this property may be ignored
- that subclasses of JComponent must override paintComponent to honor this property.

Putting setBackground in the constructor, and adding these two lines of code in `paintComponent` (before painting the red line) makes the panel black.

```
g.setColor(getBackground());
g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Also note that Swing components should always be created and modified in the EDT. Your main method should be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainFrame appFrame = new MainFrame();
            appFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            appFrame.setSize(300, 275);
            appFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting multithreading? Hmm, will have to learn it.

Comment: I'm not suggesting multi-threading. All the swing components may only be used by a single thread: the event dispatch thread. Your code is using components in the main thread. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading, which is linked to by the javadoc of every swing component.